# How to post a comment to JIRA using JIRA API using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jira, jira-rest-api

I am writing an API to add/post comments to JIRA issue using Node JS but due to some error in the code it throws me an error and the comment does not get added to the JIRA issue

```
                var infix = "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/";
                var postfix = ticketNumber;
                infix = infix + postfix + "/comment";

                var bodyData = `{
                    "visibility": {
                    "type": "role",
                    "value": "Administrators"
                    },
                    "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed semper quam laoreet nisi egestas at posuere augue semper."
                    }`;

                var options = {
                    method: "POST",
                    url: infix,
                    auth: {
                        username: option.storageConfig.id,
                        password: option.storageConfig.pass,
                    },
                    headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: bodyData,
                };
                request(options, async function (error, response, body) {
                    if (error) throw new Error(error);
                    console.log(
                        "Response: " + response.statusCode + " " + response.statusMessage
                    );
                    if (response.statusCode == 204 || response.statusCode == 200) {
                        console.log("Comment has been added to the ticket");
                    } else {
                        console.log("Error adding comments");
                    }
                });
```

Can somebody guide me where exactly I am going wrong?
I checked different links but was not successful in getting the putout

I am giving "lorem ipsum comment" as my comment, but when I refresh the issue it doesn't add in the issue.
I just want a simple solution which can post a comment to the JIRA
Note: ticket number is coming from front-end.

Comment: What is the error code throwing ?

Comment: @jsduniya it throws the console.log("Error adding comments"), no other error, so I think I am doing something wrong in the code which is not allowing me to add comments

Comment: First you have to check whether your option object is correct and second thing is check where that api is hit server and returning any response